# Why can't I clear cookies in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

cookies just keeps adding on and on when I register a new user.

`userRoutes.js`:

```
const { registerUser, loginUser, registerVerify } = require("./userController");

const express=require('express')
const router=express.Router()

router
    .route('/register')
    .post(registerUser)

module.exports=router
```

`userController.js`:

```
const User = require("./userModel");
const validator = require("validator");
const jwt=require('jsonwebtoken')


const sendToken = function (email) {
  let data = {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRE_SHORT,
    email,
  };
  let token = jwt.sign(data, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY);

  return token;
};

exports.registerUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { userName, email, password, confirmPassword } = req.body;
    let user = [
      { userName, email, password, confirmPassword, createdAt: Date.now() },
    ];

    //passwords do not match error
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      throw "Password doesn't match Confirm Password.";
    }

    //email not valid error
    if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
      throw "Email not valid.";
    }

    //user already logged in error
    if (await User.findOne({ email })) {
      throw "User already exists. Please login";
    }

    //create user
    await User.create(user);

    //assign token
    let token = sendToken(email);

    //clear cookie
    
    res.status(200).clearCookie('token').cookie(token, 'token', {maxAge: 360000}).json({
      message: "Please fill the required text send via email",
      token,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    // console.log(err)
    res.status(400).json({
      message: "Signup Not Successfull",
      err,
    });
  }
};
```

I've tried:

```js
router
    .route('/register',{ credentials: 'same-origin'})
    .post(registerUser)
```

```js
router
    .route('/register',{ credentials: 'include'})
    .post(registerUser)
```

```js
router
    .route('/register',{ withCredentials: true})
    .post(registerUser)
```

Comment: You don't need to clear and create a new one. when you send a cookie with the same key it overrides itself

Comment: @I.sh. it does not in my case. I see 1 new cookie everytime I try to register a new user.

Comment: Of course you will... you put the actual token where you supposed to put the key... here is the correct way: `.cookie("token", token,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct way for creating a cookie:

```
res.cookie('token', token, {maxAge: 360000});
```

Note: You don't need to clear and create a new one.
when you send a cookie with the same key it overrides itself.